# ADAL Android library crash

Tags: android, authentication, nullpointerexception, azure-active-directory, adal

The app crashes for most of the users after an update from the Play store.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.TokenCacheAccessor.isMultipleMRRTsMatchingGivenApp(SourceFile:440)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenSilentHandler.tryMRRT(SourceFile:268)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenSilentHandler.tryRT(SourceFile:216)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenSilentHandler.getAccessToken(SourceFile:114)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.tryAcquireTokenSilentLocally(SourceFile:499)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.acquireTokenSilentFlow(SourceFile:475)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.tryAcquireTokenSilent(SourceFile:379)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.performAcquireTokenRequest(SourceFile:358)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest.access$200(SourceFile:57)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$1.run(SourceFile:131)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

ADAL library version - 3.0.2

Comment: Are you using proguard, dexguard or similar tools?

Comment: @Luke Duda yes I am using proguard.
com.microsoft.aad.adal.t0.a SourceFile:83
com.microsoft.aad.adal.e.c SourceFile:15
com.microsoft.aad.adal.e.d SourceFile:15
com.microsoft.aad.adal.d.a SourceFile:63
com.microsoft.aad.adal.d.d SourceFile:3
com.microsoft.aad.adal.d.b SourceFile:2
com.microsoft.aad.adal.d.a SourceFile:3
com.microsoft.aad.adal.d$a.run SourceFile:4
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641
java.lang.Thread.run Thread.java:919

Answer (score 0):

It's known to the project developers as an error while using proguard/dexguard.

Sample issues:
- [ADAL Plugin integration is crashing with proguard/dexguard](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/1487)
- [Resiliency fix to not crash: Null Pointer Exception at isMultipleRTsMatchingGivenAppAndResource](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/1278)
- [NullPointerException in isMultipleMRRTsMatchingGivenApp](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/1278#issuecomment-629948465)

Comment: I didn't add any lines to disable obfuscation of ADAL classes in proguard file.